# Check if all words starts with specific character with regex

Tags: html, angular, regex

Im doing form validation in angular, and I want to check if ALL words in string starts with character 'Z'. I use it in pattern so i can dynamically change class of input.

So far I managed to do this:

```js
pattern="^Z\w*"
```

But it only check if whole string starts with 'Z'. It will match 'Z something', and it shouldn't cos I want this to be true only when all words start with 'Z', for example 'ZSTH ZANOTHER'.

I tried also

```js
(^Z\w*)|(^\sZ\w*)
```

But it still checks only the beginning of string, due to '^' operator. Is there anything i can do to check all words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
pattern="(?:Z\w*(?:\W+Z\w*)*)?"
```

Note that the full pattern (after the HTML processes this string into a regex pattern) will look like `^(?:(?:Z\w*(?:\W+Z\w*)*)?)$`. It matches

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

    - `Z\w*` - `Z` and zero or more word chars
    - `(?:\W+Z\w*)*` - zero or more occurrences of one or more non-word chars and then `Z` and zero or more word chars
  - `)?` - end of the second non-capturing group
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.